# Jenkins pipeline execution order

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently building a pipeline in Jenkins for a node application.

The stages will be:

- checkout the code
- update dependencies
- run tests

and I was sending notifications via slack in the post section.

However I wanted to change this to make it a little slicker and mention specific users in a slack channel.  So, I found out that I can get the committer name using:

```
AUTHOR_NAME = bat (
script: "git show -s --format='%%an' HEAD",
returnStdout: true
).split('\r\n')[2].trim()
```

and using a switch (for a proof here) I can use slackSend and mention the userId of the appropriate person.  Everything seemed to work ok when I was testing it with just me, then I got someone else to try it.  And I was mentioned in the slack comment again, not the user.  I tried it and this time the other person was mentioned.

After a bit of playing it seems that the code to get the name is running one commit behind.  I had placed this code inside the environment block - but should this code be called as part of the git checkout? After the git checkout?

Comment: Your script which invokes `git show` is requesting the author name, not the commiter name - `--format='%%an'`. This might be an issue. Replace `%%an` witn `%%cn`. I would run this after the git checkout, not as a part of it (separation of roles - 1st checkout phase, then 2nd execution phase).

Comment: @Rann Lifshitz I had tried to run this after the checkout, in its' own "stage" - but it seems to throw an error (from memory I think it complains that the code should be in a step - but it is in a step)

Comment: Please post the errors you are receiving - I can not help you otherwise.

Comment: I got it sorted.  I had to eclose the AUTHOR_NAME = bat(...) command within a script block

Comment: Cool - You should post your solution as an answer to your own question